# Python, speech_recognition tool does not recognize .wav file

Tags: python, google-api, speech-recognition

I have generated a .wav audio file containing some speech with some other interference speech in the background. 
This code worked for me for a test .wav file:

```
    import speech_recognition as sr

    r = sr.Recognizer()
    with sr.WavFile(wav_path) as source:
        audio = r.record(source)

    text = r.recognize_google(audio)
```

If I use my .wav file, I get the following error:

> ValueError: Audio file could not be read as PCM WAV, AIFF/AIFF-C, or Native FLAC; check if file is corrupted or in another format

The situation slightly improves if I save this .wav file with soundfile:

```
    import soundfile as sf        

    wav, samplerate = sf.read(wav_path)
    sf.write(saved_wav_path, original_wav, fs)
```

and then load the new saved_wav_path back into the first block of code, this time I get:

> if not isinstance(actual_result, dict) or len(actual_result.get("alternative", [])) == 0: raise UnknownValueError()

The audio files were saved as

```
    wavfile.write(wav_path, fs, data)
```

where wav_path = 'data.wav'. Any ideas?

SOLUTION:

Saving the audio data the following way generates the correct .wav files:

```
    import wavio
    wavio.write(wav_path, data, fs ,sampwidth=2)
```

Comment: Are you sure your file really is a WAV file, not some other kind of file that you just put 
a `.wav` extension on? And that it's a simple PCM s16 or u8 WAV file, as opposed to, say, an MP3-compressed WAV file?

Comment: WAV file is not WAV file. It is container format that can take different types of audio streams. Check that the type and attributes of the audio stream fit your tool.

Comment: The audio files were saved with wavfile.write("data.wav", fs, data) so, as you all said, it might have saved in the wrong format. Do you know an alternative solution?

Comment: *"The audio files were saved with wavfile.write("data.wav", fs, data)..."*  Please add this information to the question.  It looks like you have that information in your [other question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52263958/python-how-to-write-pcm-wav-files); it should be here, too.  In fact, that question is effectively a duplicate of this one, isn't it?

Comment: you got any solution for this `r.recognize_google(audio)` ??? i got the same error too.

Comment: @Phys in your solution, is 'data' an audio file (for example: 
import speech_recognition as sr

data = sr.AudioFile('harvard.wav') )?

Comment: Yes, it's an audio file.

Comment: @Phys what is data in this case?

Comment: i got this error: AttributeError: 'AudioFile' object has no attribute 'min'

Answer (score 7, accepted):

From a brief look at the code in the `speech_recognition` package, it appears that it uses `wave` from the Python standard library to read WAV files.  Python's `wave` library does not handle floating point WAV files, so you'll have to ensure that you use `speech_recognition` with files that were saved in an integer format.

SciPy's function `scipy.io.wavfile.write` will create an integer file if you pass it an array of integers.  So if `data` is a floating point numpy array, you could try this:

```
from scipy.io import wavfile

# Convert `data` to 32 bit integers:
y = (np.iinfo(np.int32).max * (data/np.abs(data).max())).astype(np.int32)

wavfile.write(wav_path, fs, y)
```

Then try to read that file with `speech_recognition`.

Alternatively, you could use [`wavio`](https://pypi.org/project/wavio/) (a small library that I created) to save your data to a WAV file. It also uses Python's `wave` library to create its output, so `speech_recognition` should be able to read the files that it creates.

Comment: Your first solution gives the second error listed in my question: so the audio variable is successfully created but there is no intelligible speech. Using wavio solved the problem, I will update my initial question with the solution. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

I couldn't figure out what the sampwidth should be for wavio from its documentation; however, I added the following line `sounddevice.default.dtype='int32', 'int32'` which allowed sounddevice, scipy.io.wavfile.write / soundfile, and speech_recognizer to finally work together.  The default dtype for sounddevice was float32 for both input and output.  I tried changing only the output but it didnt work.  Weirdly, audacity still thinks the output files are in float32.  I am not suggesting this is a better solution, but it did work with both soundfile and scipy.

I also noticed another oddity.  When sounddevice.default.dtype was left at the default [float32, float32] and I opened the resulting file in audacity. From audacity, I exported it and this exported wav would work with speechrecognizer.  Audacity says its export is float32 and the same samplerate, so I don't fully understand. I am a noob but looked at both files in a hex editor and they look the same for the first 64 hex values then they differ...  so it seems like the header is the same.  Those two look very different than the file I made using int32 output, so seems like there's another factor at play...

Answer (score 0):

Similar to Warren's answer, I was able to resolve this issue by rewriting the WAV file using `pydub`:

```
from pydub import AudioSegment

filename = "payload.wav"  # File that already exists.
                       
sound = AudioSegment.from_mp3(filename)
sound.export(filename, format="wav")
```