# How to solve "Audio file is corrupted or in another format" while I can listen the file, and the file is in the right format?

Tags: python, speech-recognition, text-to-speech, wav

I'am working on a Speech to text assignment. I have an example working with an example audio file, but when I try my own audio file I receive this error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):

  File "<ipython-input-27-43c56c192b14>", line 1, in <module>
    with input_audio as source:

  File "C:\Users\AppData\Local\Continuum\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\speech_recognition\__init__.py", line 236, in __enter__
    raise ValueError("Audio file could not be read as PCM WAV, AIFF/AIFF-C, or Native FLAC; check if file is corrupted or in another format")

ValueError: Audio file could not be read as PCM WAV, AIFF/AIFF-C, or Native FLAC; check if file is corrupted or in another format
```

**My Question: What can I do, to analyze my Audio file? Since It looks like it is in the right format..**

I googled, and found another question on [Stackoverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52249985/python-speech-recognition-tool-does-not-recognize-wav-file). The author was mentioning that probably, the type of WAV file is wrong. However, when I check the type of my audio, it looks right:

```
import fleep

with open("my_own_audio.wav", "rb") as file:
    info = fleep.get(file.read(128))

print(info.extension)
['wav']
```

My code so far (it is the same as [the Ultimate Guide To Speech Recognition](https://realpython.com/python-speech-recognition/))

```
import os
import speech_recognition as sr
os.chdir(r'C:\Desktop\Speech_to_Text')

r = sr.Recognizer()
input_audio = sr.AudioFile('harvard.wav')  # The example works! 
input_audio = sr.AudioFile('my_own_audio.wav') # Will throw the error! 

type(input_audio) # For both, it will print Out[29]: speech_recognition.AudioFile

# This chunk will throw the error! 
with input_audio as source: 
    # If the data has a lot of noise. 
    r.adjust_for_ambient_noise(source)
    audio = r.record(source)

r.recognize_google(audio, show_all = True)
```

Comment: Can you add your wav file's header (the first 44 bytes)?

Comment: @TDG sure, can you please help me how I can get the first 44 bytes? And do you know if the data is then still anonymous? Many thanks!

Comment: You should open the file with some hex editor, it will display the file byte by byte (I use HxD). The first 44 bytes are the file's header - number of channels, sample rate etc. It contains no private data at all. You can read about wav file's structure and you will see yourself.